# Bounded appscript to google sheet is not working after being shared with java drive SDK v3

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Here is my issue.
I have a spreadsheet template bounded to a google appscript.
The spreadsheet is owned by a [google service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). 
For the moment the appscript is very simple.
It contains only one method that log a message.
I then programatically:

1. copy the spreadsheet with the drive SDK v3
2. share it with a user, right being set to 'writer'

When accessing the copy logged as the new user, I can't run the script nor add any new libraries.
Each attempt displays an error message:

"*We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again*"

However doing the very same operations manually or using the API explorer does not trigger any issue and I am able to run the script or add libraries.

**Does anyone has the same issue and succeded to solve it ?**

thx !

Comment: By the way, I also tried the copy operation with appScript and I have no problem to run the script in the copy.  
Seems like the problem is related with Drive Sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys,

We found the issue. In my description I omited to say that the spreadsheet was owned by a google service account.
For a reason yet to be discovered, copying a document with a bounded script from a google service account 'breaks' the script.
I know rely on a normal user account to share the wanted document.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [Features and Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#features_and_limitations) in Importing and Exporting Projects,

> 6. Only standalone scripts can be imported or exported. [Container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) scripts cannot be accessed through the Google Drive REST API.

You may want to also check [Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) for more information on how bound scripts work and behave.

Comment: I don't think I am in the scope of this limitation. I don't need to access an appscript projet. I just want to copy a file containing a bounded script. According the documentation "Only users who have permission to edit a spreadsheet, document, or form can run its bound script".   
But I don't get this behavior through the drive SDK.   
I dont' see either why it should be related to the Drive REST API since using the API explorer, the flow is working (the shared user can run the script).